# Error Running Azure Static Web App with NPM Workspaces Enabled

Tags: azure, monorepo, azure-static-web-app

I have a basic Next.js app in a monorepo project using NPM workspaces ([repo](https://github.com/westonsankey/next-mono)). The app can be deployed via GitHub actions without error to an Azure Static Web App, but I get a 502 error when accessing it. When the NPM workspaces configuration is removed from the top-level `package.json` file, the app works without issue. Other than the 502 network response when browsing the site, there are no other informative errors describing the root cause.

Working `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Failing `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Are there additional build steps I need to include in the GitHub actions configuration for NPM workspaces support? Or does Azure Static Web Apps not support monorepo setups using workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

A Next.js application's static export can be enabled by adding `next export` to the build npm script in **package.json**.
Set `IS_STATIC_EXPORT` to `true` in the Static Web Apps job of the GitHub Actions workflow like below:-

**In order to run next export make sure you have next cli installed.**

```js
npm install -g next
next export
```

I have referred this [**github repository**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-static-export.md) for the deployment.

***My github action workflow:-***

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_TREE_01B7E9E10 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "out" 
        env: 
          IS_STATIC_EXPORT: true
          

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_TREE_01B7E9E10 }}
          action: "close"
```

[image]

[image]

Also, Monorepos are now supported in Azure static web app have a look at the comments in this **[github issue](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/11#issuecomment-706290581)** by **miwebst**

Comment: Those are the general instructions for deploying a static Next.js app, but my issue is with deploying an app in a monorepo; specifically, the adding the single `workspaces` config to the top-level `package.json` causes a failure.